# Python: Importing parent and child classes from different modules

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-import

I have a parent class in one file, a child class in another, and I'm trying to use them in a third.  Sort of like this:

test1.py

```
class Parent(object):
    def spam(self):
        print "something"
```

test2.py

```
class Child(Parent):
    def eggs(self):
        print "something else"
```

test3.py

```
from test1 import *
from test2 import *
test = Child()
```

running test3.py gives me the following:

```
File "[path]\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
class Child(Parent):
NameError: name 'Parent' is not defined
```

Do I need to just keep my parent and child classes all in the same place?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that `from foo import *` is bad. It makes this kind of confusion far easier to run into, and harder to reason through. If you'd just done `import test1`, the answer would be obvious: you need `class Child(test1.Parent)`, and therefore you need to `import test1`. By doing it this way, the answer is hard to explain—you need to know about how per-module globals work, and how `import` works, before it's obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import the `Parent` model in `test2.py` as well

```
from test1 import Parent

class Child(Parent):
    def eggs(self):
        print "something else"
```

Comment: Thanks, karthikr, that worked.  I figured there was a simple solution to this that I was completely ignorant of.

Comment: @karthikr, it is a problem if a module imports the same module as another one of its imports does? For example, let's say `B` imports `A` and `C` imports `A` and `B`. Is this a problem?

Comment: Well it depends, but for the most part, if A is already in context, then python is smart enough not to import it again. However, the order of imports do matter.